# how to use PrincipalPermissionAttribute class

Tags: c#, web-services, restful-authentication

I have a webservice exposing certain methods. I want to restrict access of some of those methods to a particular group of users. On searching over the internet, I found that PrincipalPermissionAttribute class is what I need, but i did not get good enough example. Can anyone explain how this works?

This is how my web.config file looks like:

```
<System.Web>
 <authentication mode="windows">
 <authorization>
   <allow user="domain\group" />
 </authorization>
</System.Web>
```

Now the webservice method (C# Rest Webservice) that I want to restrict access is:

```
public void DeleteAction(string resourceId)
{
}
```

I have done two things:

1)

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, role="domain\\group")]
   public void DeleteAction(string resourceId)
   {
      // delete action
   }
```

I get the following error message: "request for principal permission failed" and the second thing is how can I make the value of role to be dynamic i.e. selecting it from Web.config file rather than hardcoding it.

2)

```
public void DeleteAction(string resourceId)
   {
     WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
     WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(wi);

     if(wp.IsInRole("domain\\group"))
     {
       // delete action
     }
   }
```

In this approach, it works fine when I use a console program to host the webservice. When this service is hosted in IIS, I am not able to get this working. The user is never identified i.e. wp.IsInRole("domain\group") is returning false.

I know, I am missing something here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a user authentication issue. If you do not know who is the user you won't be able to know the permissions using the WindowsPrincipal.

Please make sure that your website is ***not*** using Asp.Net impersonation and that the forms authentication is enabled.

IIS -> WebSite -> Authentication

Take a look to the [IIS Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Regards,